# Installing Vmware on ubuntu

Tags: vmware

So for a while now that I'm trying to install vmware on my ubuntu, I managed to do it (easly) on 16.04 64 bit
But sadly I'm working with Cisco software that requires 
Linux 32 bit OS.
So now I'm using ubuntu 16.04 32 bit and I keep failing starting that Vmware on my ubuntu.
The farthest i reached is sofware seems to start, I can see logo flash on the left but than it's closing itself.
I'm trying to install Vmware 10 since that's the latest version supports 32bit OS.
Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: What exactly was/is preventing you from running 32bit software in a 64bit OS? The opposite can't be done but 32bit software at most will pull some 32bit dependencies, depending on the software, when installed in a 64bit OS.

Comment: I installed virtual router ( cisco c5921). I have tried to run it on 64 bit but failed.

Comment: Yes, it says: *The Cisco 5921 ESR is a 32-bit application. It will work on a 64-bit Linux system, provided you install and use the 32-bit libraries* at http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/solutions/GGSG-Engineering/Cisco_5921/Cisco_5921_ESR_Integration.pdf . And why do you have the 10.04 tag and what has VMware to do with it anyway?

Comment: I'm working on a project that includes the virtual router with microsoft OS( server 2003). Sadly I have to use server 2003 and router need linux so I'm using virtual machine to run the server on the linux. Since I'm using 32bit OS The vmware 10 is latest version support 32bit

Comment: Sorry, this has nothing to do with Ubuntu. You're trying to run VMware for Windows in Windows and misunderstanding a few thing along the way. VMware 64bit supports 32bit VMs. A 32bit VMware running in a 32bit host also supports 32bit VMs. You may want to go to https://superuser.com/ for help with Windows software. And 10.04 refers to a EoL Ubuntu release, unrelated to any VMware version if that was your intention.

Comment: My problem was running the software itself on ubuntu what I'm running later in virtual machine doesn't concern you. My problem was running 10.06 vmware 32 bit on ubuntu 16.04 32 bit failed. And it failed the way I see icon flash on bar and than closes, I believe that's ubuntu thing

Comment: Why do you need *virtualization* software to run *native* Linux software in Ubuntu? The more you say the less this whole thing makes sense. Please clarify: Which OS is the host?

Comment: Host is the Ubuntu 16.04 32bit
Virtual router, Cisco c5921 running in background.
Vmware 10.06 runs on ubuntu and inside there will be win server 2003

Comment: I've removed the incorrect tag and also retracted the off-topic flag. It's on-topic for sure now that you finally made it clear. However, in a nutshell and as commented in the beginning, this is a problem you created for yourself. Older VMware versions may not work at all in newer kernels and there's no valid reason to use a 32bit OS with 64bit hardware. The 32bit software you need runs in 64bit (please refer to user's manual and all other VMware online resources).

Comment: Now it does seems more logical to try and make it on 64 bit OS,
in the menual I see it's possible to run the C5921 ESr on 64 with the libraries but I can't find the required libraries, can you please help me with
getting those libraries?